# MEAN development stack failed to deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy MEAN stack using Google Developers Console, no success. I tried several times, the error was always the same (below). Do you have any idea why it keeps failing?

> Your MEAN development stack failed to deploy
>   Sep 16, 2014 11:34:59 AM
>   meanDevelopmentFirewall: DEPLOYED
>   meanStackBox: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
>   Replica mean-2jmy failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
>   What to do next:
>
> Note the error listed above.
>   Delete the stack.
>   Correct the error (if you can).
>   Try again to deploy the stack.
>   Get help at Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just rolled out a fix to our MEAN.io stack deployment today.  Please try again at your convenience.

Comment: This is happening to me today. 

May 27, 2015, 9:06:09 AM
meanStackBox: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
Replica mean-foo failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.

Comment: I've tried for the last 2 days and can't get the click-to-deploy for MEAN to work.  DEPLOYMENT_FAILED Replica State
changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times."  I tried deleting all instances and still no luck.