# Click to Deploy Mean stack is not working

Tags: google-app-engine, web-deployment, mean-stack, google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy MEAN stack using Google Developers Console, and failed after trying several times, the error is always the same. Is there any fix around this other than deploying the whole stack manually ?

Your MEAN development stack failed to deploy
Dec 1, 2014, 3:12:51 PM
meanStackBox: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
Replica mean-zeuw failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
What to do next:

Review the troubleshooting guide
Delete stack

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error as well. Tried changing the Zone as well as other variables under the Advanced options but nothing is working so far. Googling shows the last time this happened a fix was needed to be deployed by Google - [MEAN development stack failed to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865459/mean-development-stack-failed-to-deploy). It took 2 days for that question to be posted and the reply from Brian who I assume must be working for Google in some capacity. So if this started to happen from yesterday then hopefully the fix will come tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this issue could be related to the zone/region settings in your instance.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522970/ruby-stack-failed-to-deploy-on-google-developers-console), where my colleague found a successful workaround.